# How to refresh a part of a page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've checked around and tried a few solutions out on here, but I can't figure out why my code doesn't work. I just want to refresh a table with a class every few seconds. Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function () {
        $('.table_class').load(document.URL + '.table_class');
    }, 3000);
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing a `space`

```
$('.table_class').load(document.URL + ' .table_class');
```

Comment: I'm still getting "Undefined is not a function". Sorry, but thanks for the input!

Comment: Ahhh! I'm using an older version of jQuery! Figured it out

Comment: @Shane what is the jquery version used

Comment: 1.11.1 . I just had to use `jQuery` instead of `$`.

Comment: @Shane then it is because of noConflict not because of jQuery version I think